# How i sholud refresh website content without navbar from GET parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, page-refresh

I have one problem becouse I don't know how I should reload content on my website when I click on the navbar, I see two different ways for this problem.

In main file index.php I load content:

```
<!-- Other HTML header --->
<body>

<div id="navbar">
    <input type="button" value="Desc">
    <input type="button" value="Arc">
</div>

<?php
     if( isset($_GET['content']) ){

        if( $_GET['content'] == "desc")
        {
             include 'content/desc.php'
        }

        if( $_GET['content'] == "arc")
        {
             include 'content/arc.php'
        }

        else
        {
             include 'content/start.php'
        }
}
?>
</body>
```

When the link don't have content parameter script return base content, but when I click the menu button the website should change content, and how i should do that ? I can reload website and set GET parameter for example index.php?content=desc but I have animate navbar and I don't want reload all web. Can I block olny navbar refresh ? Meybe I sould do this with AJAX ? But I don't know i should put file struct on the serwer for users in JavaScript file?
In on click event in JavaScript file:

```
$("#content-div).load("content/desc.php);
```

This way is good ? I have some fear for this way, becouse I put struct file on the serwer in file who can see everybody.

Comment: What does it matter that anybody could see the output of `content/desc.php` - you want to show that output to the user anyway ...

Comment: When i do this that user could be use this for example www.myweb.pl/content/desc.php and show only content without rest website. Correctly is www.myweb.pl/index.php?content=desc I don't know what user could be do with this. How i should do that ?

Comment: Well then make the request to `myajaxscript?content=desc` instead, and place that same logic that includes the right content in there ...

Comment: In JavaScript ? I thought to make request only to index.php from user side, but when i make request to index.php with parameter using AJAX I will get new content and all website and when I load this to div-content I will get content and navbar in this div.I need get parameter in link becouse when somebody want to sent to somebody (friend) link to concrete content he send link: www.website.pl/index.php?content=desc

Comment: Well then make your index.php not output all of that other HTML code if the parameter is set.

Comment: Yes, but what when I have link to my page and I click this www.mypage.pl/index.php?content=desc ? index.php return only content, how can I recognize load new content from click on the navbar and load website with parameter from link who sent for example my friend ?

Comment: Pretty sure jQuery adds a specific request header for AJAX requests, so you could check for that in your server-side script. Or you add an additional parameter - `index.php?content=desc` delivers the full page, whereas `index.php?content=desc&mode=ajax` returns only the content you want to dynamically insert into the already loaded page.

Comment: Or you just load the complete page using .load anyway, and make it insert only a specific element from that document into the current one (see section "Loading Page Fragments" in the documentation.) That would of course load more content than is actually needed - but depending on how big your HTML "outside" of the actual content is, that might be negligible.

Comment: I will search other way without this specific header for future problems without jQuery. Ok, but what if user will make this request    index.php?content=desc&mode=something-bad ?     index.php?content=desc will return full page,  index.php?content=desc&mode=ajax will return only content ? Still user can get only content when he make request index.php?content=desc&mode=ajaxin web browser. $.get don't change link i web browser, i must change that in JavaScript and meybe i should send this parameters in post method and change link in browser with JavaScript ?

Comment: _"Still user can get only content when he make request index.php?content=desc&mode=ajaxin web browser"_ - again: So what/who cares? They would see the content inside the page anyway. If they want to make requests that only deliver partial content and not a proper, whole document ... let them, that's their business.

Comment: Ok :) I think i have last question, what if user copy link whith &mode=ajax and sent to somebody who want to see concrete content ?

Comment: That's tough luck then :) But the user would not see those URLs anywhere _on_ your page, they would have to start digging into the code or explicitly copy the URL from somewhere where it does show up, like the network tab in the browser developer tools - how likely is that?

Comment: From JavaScript file ? $.get("index.php?content=desc&mode=ajax" )... or i wrong thinked about ...

Comment: _"From JavaScript file ?"_ - and how many regular users would look there in the first place ...? Stop overthinking this. If it should turn out later that this happens on a massive scale, and that therefor the End of the World is nigh ... then you can still adapt the code to some other mechanism then.

Comment: Ok, to finish this question, I get only content with &mode=ajax. When i click the button in navbar i call $.get("index.php?content=desc&mode=ajax"... in onclick event. This call don't change link in web browser, when I click the button and load new content I have still index.php link. I must change the link to index.php?content=desc with JavaScript. Right ?

Comment: You will need to use the HTML5 History API for that. (Because if you change the _actual_ location, then it would load the complete page directly, circumventing what you are trying to do with AJAX here.)